# HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in file_get_contents

Tags: php, http, file-get-contents

I have a link here`http://www.example.com/Movies.aspx?movname=Raja Natwarlal`

Here is my code

```
file_get_contents($link, false, $context);
```

It give me this error

```
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

I also tried this code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); //get the code of request
curl_close($ch);
```

It give me $httpCode=400

Comment: First it might be worth a try to propperly http escape that blank in the url and second it might well be that the server denies the request and indeed sends an error 400 by purpose.

Comment: I have also tried urlencode() but no luck

Comment: Using `urlencode()` on the whole url does not make any sense. That is not what I suggested.

Comment: Have a try with these variants: `http://www.example.com/Movies.aspx?movname=Raja+Natwarlal` and `http://www.example.com/Movies.aspx?movname=Raja%20Natwarlal`...

Comment: You are welcome :-) I reposted the suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL you posted is not valid in a technical way. A browser will take care of that if you enter such a URL, but on a more technical level you have to deal with such details yourself.

In this case there is a blank inside the urls request parameter. Such a character is not valid in a URL. Therefore you have to escape it. Have a try with these variants:

- http://www.example.com/Movies.aspx?movname=Raja+Natwarlal
- http://www.example.com/Movies.aspx?movname=Raja%20Natwarlal

Note that you cannot simply use a function like `urlencode()` to process the whole URL. That would also escape things like slashes and the like. That function is meant to escape a string such that it can be used as a single token *inside* an URL.